# Sencha Touch - deselect list item?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

I'm working on a Sencha Touch application, and have a list of contacts. When a list item is tapped, an ActionSheet is displayed showing some basic functions (such as call, delete and ignore). Unfortunately, when the user taps and the ActionSheet is fired, the List item remains selected underneath the overlay (see the screenshot below):

[image: Screenshot of iOS Simulator]

Here's the function bound to the itemTap event:

```
itemTap: function(list, index)
{
    // Deselect the selected record:
    var currentRecord = list.getStore().getAt(index);
    currentRecord.forename      = currentRecord.get('forename');
    currentRecord.surname       = currentRecord.get('surname');
    currentRecord.phoneNumber   = currentRecord.get('phoneNumber');
    currentRecord.shortFullName = currentRecord.forename + ' ' +  currentRecord.surname[0];

    list.getStore().deselect(index, true);

    callButton.setText('Call ' + currentRecord.shortFullName + ' (' + currentRecord.phoneNumber + ')');
    unfriendButton.setText('Remove ' + currentRecord.shortFullName + ' as friend');
    friendActionSheet.show();
}
```

Unfortunately, `list.getStore().deselect(index, true)` returns the following error: `Object [object Object] has no method 'deselect'`

Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong, or how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This works for me:

```
    listeners: {
        itemtap: function(dv, ix, item, e) {
            // Clear the selection soon
            setTimeout(function(){dv.deselect(ix);},500);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, assume you're the same Chris that tackled it over on the Sencha forums for me. It did indeed work, and I have given you some props for your help!

Comment: I prefer this method much more than the `disableSelection: true` method mentioned below (although it works great) because this highlights the user's selection as usual then deselects it, whereas `disableSelection` never highlights a selection to begin with.

Answer (score 11):

In Sencha Touch 2, use disableSelection: true, while creating a list

```
Ext.define('App.view.NewsList',{
extend: 'Ext.List',
xtype: NEWS_LIST,

config: {
    store: NEWS_FEED,
    //deselectOnContainerClick: true,// not working in Sencha Touch 2
    disableSelection: true, // since Sencha Touch 2
    itemTpl: '{heading}'
} 
});
```

Comment: In case of **nestedlist** it's also possible to use that option. But you have to add it to `listConfig` property like this: `listConfig: { disableSelection: true }`

Comment: For some applications of nestedList you can also set the `allowDeselect` property to true.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to clear the whole list:

```
var selModel = app.views.notesList.deselect(app.views.notesList.getSelectedRecords());
```

Comment: This worked on an Ext.dataview.List, except using getSelection() instead of getSelectedRecords(). That was with Sencha Touch 2.1.

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` is really not a good solution here. It should be like this:

```
 listeners: {
        itemtap: function(list, ix, item, e) {
            // Clear the selection soon
            list.deselect(list.getSelectedRecords());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried to recreate your problem but you may want to try:

```
list.deselect(currentRecord, true);
```

After you do that you may have to call

```
doLayout()
```

or

```
doComponentLayout()
```

to refresh the view.

Comment: Thanks @ballmw, but `doLayout()` is a method of the Container class, and does not belong to a List object. `list.refresh()` clears the selection, but also removes the temporary blue highlighting which isn't good for HCI...

Comment: Good to see you found an answer!

Answer (score 0):

This drove me INSANE.

While the approved answer will work, its worth noting that you can do it with a delay(like nested list does too) like this:

```
    var selModel = app.views.VideosList.items.items[0].getSelectionModel();
    Ext.defer(selModel.deselectAll, 200, selModel);
```

I put that in my controller (so its called when the view changes), where app.views.VideosList is my main panel and app.views.VideosList.items.items[0] is the list in that panel.

Answer (score 0):

this did it for me (sencha touch 2.3):

```
list = Ext.Viewport.down('nestedlist');
list.getActiveItem().deselectAll();
```